# How to find the correct Power Mode to use for MaaS

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to set up my own little cloud at home, so I got a few Cenovo Mini PCs and installed Ubuntu Server on them. I would like to manage them using [MaaS](https://maas.io), but in order to control the power cycle I need to identify the Power Type.

What is the best way to approach this on a device? Is there a way to do it through EFMI? I suspect that this hardware doesn't support what I need, but I'd like to understand how to look this up in the future.